# Azure Message Bus Retrieving Data Asynchronously and returning it via controller action

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, async-await, azureservicebus

I have a .NetCore project that sends and recieves messages to and from the Azure Service Bus.

To receive a message the following works quite well:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        private static async Task MainAsync()
        {
            queueClient = new QueueClient(ServiceBusConnectionString, QueueName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
            ReceiveMessages();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop receiving messages.");
            Console.ReadKey();

            // Close the client after the ReceiveMessages method has exited.
            await queueClient.CloseAsync();
        }

        // Receives messages from the queue in a loop
        private static void ReceiveMessages()
        {
            try
            {
                // Register a OnMessage callback
                queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(
                    async (message, token) =>
                    {
                        // Process the message
                        Console.WriteLine($"Received message: SequenceNumber:{message.SequenceNumber} Body:{message.GetBody<string>()}");

                        // Complete the message so that it is not received again.
                        // This can be done only if the queueClient is opened in ReceiveMode.PeekLock mode.
                        await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.LockToken);
                    },
                    new RegisterHandlerOptions() {MaxConcurrentCalls = 1, AutoComplete = false});
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} > Exception: {exception.Message}");
            }
        }
```

I am trying to port this console app to a webapi project. With the idea being when the api is called, it will return the current messages in the queue.

The way I am doing this is below:

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {
            queueClient = new QueueClient(ServiceBusConnectionString, QueueName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);

            MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            // Close the client after the ReceiveMessages method has exited.
            await queueClient.CloseAsync();
            return Ok(nameList);
        }
        private static async Task MainAsync()
        {
            queueClient = new QueueClient(ServiceBusConnectionString, QueueName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
            ReceiveMessages();

            //Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop receiving messages.");
            //Console.ReadKey();

            //// Close the client after the ReceiveMessages method has exited.
            //await queueClient.CloseAsync();
        }

        // Receives messages from the queue in a loop
        private static void ReceiveMessages()
        {
            try
            {
                // Register a OnMessage callback
                queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(
                    async (message, token) =>
                    {
                        // Process the message
                        nameList.Add(
                            $"Received message: SequenceNumber:{message.SequenceNumber} Body:{message.GetBody<string>()}");
                        //reList.Add(message.GetBody<string>());
                        // Complete the message so that it is not received again.
                        // This can be done only if the queueClient is opened in ReceiveMode.PeekLock mode.
                        await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.LockToken);
                    },
                    new RegisterHandlerOptions() {MaxConcurrentCalls = 1, AutoComplete = false});
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} > Exception: {exception.Message}");
            }

        }
```

This ends up with the queueClient.CloseAsync(); getting called before the messages are even retrieved from the queue.

I have tried various ways of accomplishing this, but it looks like my async programming is simply not working.

Any help with this is much much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're registering a handler and you're going back.The messages in the queue starts to be processed after you return.OnMessage makes sense for the "pub/sub" structure.You can use "pub/sub" to return the response to the client as the queue comes in, but you need to push the incoming messages to the client.(for example with SignalR).You want to return all the messages in the queue after a request.You can receive messages from the queue one by one (In a loop with Receive method) and then you will return the response.

```
   while (true) 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            //receive messages from Queue 
            message = queueClient.Receive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)); 
            if (message != null) 
            { 
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Message received: Id = {0}, Body = {1}", message.MessageId, message.GetBody<string>())); 
                // Further custom message processing could go here… 
                message.Complete(); 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                //no more messages in the queue 
                break; 
            } 
        } 
        catch (MessagingException e) 
        { 
            if (!e.IsTransient) 
            { 
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message); 
                throw; 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                HandleTransientErrors(e); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    queueClient.Close(); 
}
```

Comment: I am trying to follow this example
https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/tree/dev/samples/ReceiveSample

I am getting this error: queueClient does not contain a definition for ReceiveAsync.

Any ideas ?